# Why does scipy.optimize.root converge to a wrong solution?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm working on a project where I am using a root solver to find some parameters for a curve which cause the curve's endpoint to be at a particular location **x1** with a particular tangent vector **n1**. The parameters I'm working with are for Frenet-Serret curves just in case it helps understand the problem.

Here's the function I'm trying to find the roots of:

```
def f(x):
  k0, k2, t0, t1, t2 = x

  # s0, s1, and s2 are references into curve
  s0.curvature = k0
  s2.curvature = k2
  s0.torsion = t0
  s1.torsion = t1
  s2.torsion = t2

  r = curve.end_point(basis=True)
  n1t, x1t = r[0][0], r[1]
  dx = x1t-x1
  dn = n1t-n1
  return [dx[0], dx[1], dx[2], sum(dn), sum(dn**2)]
```

Since the input is a 5-vector it expects a 5-vector as output, and there wasn't a really natural way to choose 5 equations. I use the components of the position difference since that makes sense, and the absolute difference of the normal vectors seemed like that would  be strong enough. I just threw in the `sum(dn)` part to hopefully give the solver a little more information.

I know I'm doing an in-place modification of a curve here, so if the solver didn't converge, it leaves that curve in a nasty state; these are actually copies and I'm checking for convergence before I accept the output. Now I'm fairly certain this isn't the issue right now since my problem occurs during convergence, so it makes me think it's something to do with how I have set up the conditions for termination.

The problem is the vast majority of the time I get good solutions, but once in a while, the solver will think it found a solution and the end point of the curve will just be way off. Or, sometimes, the solver will get stuck in a rut and several solutions in sequence will be very bad. Am I missing something? Are my conditions not strong enough or is something else the matter?

EDIT:

Someone asked for more information about the result object scipy was giving me. I ran this trial with `xtol=1e-6` until the calculated end point and end tangent seem to be getting much farther than 0.1 units from the target.

```
*******************************************************************************
Something seems to be the matter!
*******************************************************************************

The solution did converge yet...

- The absolute difference in the end point is 0.0108799344285 
- The absolute difference in the end tangent is 0.225645622344

Here is the result from scipy:

  status: 1
 success: True
     qtf: array([-0.05326282, -0.02382437,  0.14675375, -0.01343988,  0.04837993])
    nfev: 51
       r: array([  4.10027838e-01,   2.80055126e-04,   2.72346438e-01,
         1.88121754e-02,   3.03986277e-03,   3.76073132e-02,
        -3.91459070e-03,  -5.44385807e-02,  -3.82769383e-02,
         1.41418659e-01,  -5.02200767e-02,  -8.25093288e-03,
         6.76335001e-02,   1.14316378e-02,   6.38501029e-05])
     fun: array([-0.06421218,  0.10206985,  0.04248109,  0.07709824,  0.071918  ])
       x: array([ -5.47581391e-02,   2.00109990e+07,   2.11915236e+01,
         6.61899661e+05,  -2.22193886e+07])
 message: 'The solution converged.'
    fjac: array([[-0.3207226 , -0.75566902,  0.53250215, -0.19842636, -0.05630082],
       [-0.02198464, -0.00102108,  0.06437769,  0.4629469 , -0.88377108],
       [-0.73103662,  0.31989562,  0.22322297,  0.48119372,  0.28614045],
       [-0.44804528,  0.39203066, -0.01871625, -0.71533847, -0.36538741],
       [ 0.40186388,  0.41586301,  0.81370645, -0.05523237,  0.01986423]])

x_calc: array([ 6.25753046,  2.99378609,  9.8221681 ])
x_target: array([ 6.31937831,  2.93663   ,  9.76062169])
t_calc: array([ 0.75316478, -0.59352174,  0.28368074])
t_target: array([ 0.40709037, -0.69479177,  0.59290963])
```

Answer (score 1):

The scipy.optimize.root function returns an [OptimizeResult](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html) object.

I am curious, what are the values of 'success', 'status' and 'message' fields in the OptimizeResult object that scipy.optimize.root is returning?

For example, the message might be something like this:

- 'The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the improvement from the last ten iterations.'

By the way, take a look at [minpack.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L222) to see some other possible problems that you might be hitting.

Comment: As far as I know all of those values indicated success; I've written code which checks the ``success`` flag and, as far as I know, I'm only accepting results which converged. I'm going to run another test so I can do a more proper post-mortem. Though, the fact that nothing jumps out from the bit of code I posted makes me think there's something else the matter that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: I have posted a little more information. The curve parameters aren't very "nice" but I doubt they should be.

Comment: I am starting to think that maybe I made a naive choice of ``xtol``. I had set it ``1e-6``, where the default appears to be ``1.49012e-08`` for the ``_root_hybr`` function. I wouldn't normally think that it would make that big of a difference, but apparently for this application it does.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem it did end up being a poor choice of tolerance.